# Are helm subcharts dependent on parent charts when using global variables?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In the [documentation](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md) for helm subcharts and globals, they list 4 details of which 2 I want to focus on

1. **A subchart is considered "stand-alone", which means a subchart can never explicitly depend on its parent chart.**
2. For that reason, a subchart cannot access the values of its parent.
3. A parent chart can override values for subcharts.
4. **Helm has a concept of global values that can be accessed by all charts.**

From the examples it seems like 1 and 4 are contradictory. If I create a global variable in the parent chart and then reference this in the sub chart, would this not create a dependency between the parent and sub charts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sub chart will still be considered "stand-alone". Using global values will create a dependency on the `values.yaml` of your parent chart (not an explicit dependency on the parent chart itself).

To overcome this, you must explicitly pass the parent values (via `--values` flag) when installing individual sub-charts. e.g.:

Supposing the following structure:

```
$ tree parent/
parent/
├── charts
│   └── child
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       └── templates
│           └── configmap.yaml
├── Chart.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

To install the `child` subchart individually, you must use:

`helm install ./parent/charts/child/ --values ./parent/values.yaml`

There is an open discussion ([#4767](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4767)) in helm project to improve this.